# Glyph 23130 missing from current font

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

> RuntimeWarning: `Glyph` 23130 missing from current font.
> `font.set_text(s, 0.0, flags=flags)`

Hello Friends I got this warning. When I'm using `matplotlib.pyplot` with `pandas`.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like a font problem. I don't know why but the following lines resolved my problem and the Chinese characters can be displayed correctly now:

```
import matplotlib as plt

plt.rcParams['font.sans-serif']=['SimHei'] #Show Chinese label
plt.rcParams['axes.unicode_minus']=False   #These two lines need to be set manually
```

Comment: Where to look for the supported font? I'm looking for Kannada Font.