# matplotlib plot with chinese label: UserWarning: Glyph 25293 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-62CD}) missing from current font

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

My code:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = ['Source Han Sans TW', 'sans-serif']
matplotlib.__version__  # 3.5.3
```

```
import math
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

size = math.ceil(len(df_attr)** (1/2))
fig = plt.figure()

for i, col in enumerate(df_attr):
    fig.add_subplot(size, size, i + 1)
    df_template_income_tax[col].value_counts().plot(kind="bar", ax=plt.gca(), title=df_attr_eng[i], rot=0)

fig.tight_layout()
```

Got errors:

```
findfont: Font family ['sans-serif'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans.
findfont: Generic family 'sans-serif' not found because none of the following families were found: SimHei
/opt/microsoft/mlserver/9.4.7/runtime/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py:13: UserWarning: Glyph 25293 (\N{CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-62CD}) missing from current font.
```

[image]

Tried some solutions from:

1. [Glyph 23130 missing from current font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65493638/glyph-23130-missing-from-current-font)
2. [How to show Chinese characters in Matplotlib graphs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68486916/how-to-show-chinese-characters-in-matplotlib-graphs)
3. official solution: https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/text_props.html#text-with-non-latin-glyphs

Is there anything need to install or another to show chinese characters?

Answer (score 0):

Check available fonts by codes below.

```py
import matplotlib.font_manager as fm

# matplotlib only know these fonts
font_list = [f for f in fm.fontManager.ttflist]

# check font names what you want
cjk_list = ['CJK', 'Han', 'CN', 'TW']

for f in font_list:
    if any(s.lower() in f.name.lower() for s in cjk_list):
        print(f'name={f.name}, path={f.fname}')
```

If you can't find your fonts, try some solutions like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68974960/8117257).